# function is not applied after a dynamic change

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var lootis = $('div > span');
var loot = 0

function loots() {
  lootis.each(function(e) {
    $(this).toggle(e >= loot && e < loot + 1);
  });
}
loots();

$('div').on('click', 'span', function(){
  loot = loot + 1;
  loots();
});

//Problem Starts Here:
$('div').on('contextmenu', 'span', function(){
  $('div').html('<span>Loot4</span> <span>Loot5</span> <span>Loot6</span>');
  loots();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span>Loot1</span>
  <span>Loot2</span>
  <span>Loot3</span>
</div>
```

Hello, I have this code here, On clicking the span is changed to the next span

On right-click the spans changes to 4 5 6, But the function loots() doesn't apply on them, it is supposed to be like 1 2 3, where only one span appears per click, What is the problem in the code?

Comment: So just call `loots()` in the contextmenu callback function.

Comment: After `$('div').html(...);` put `loots();`

Comment: @KodosJohnson did it, still the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> On right-click the spans changes to 4 5 6, But the function loots()
>   doesn't apply on them

You get the dom elements once at the beginning of the JS code:

```
var lootis = $('div > span');
```

But when you change the innerHTML of the `<div>`:

```
$('div').html('<span>Loot4</span> <span>Loot5</span> <span>Loot6</span>');
```

The `lootis` still refers the old elements and not the new ones. All you need to do is re-fetch the elements from the dom:

```js
(function() {

  var lootis = $('div > span');
  var loot = 0

  function loots() {
    lootis.each(function(e) {
      $(this).toggle(e >= loot && e < loot + 1);
    });
  }
  loots();

  $('div').on('click', 'span', function() {;
    loot = loot + 1;
    loots();
    console.log("click");
  });

  //Problem Starts Here:
  $('div').on('contextmenu', 'span', function() {
    $('div').html('<span>Loot4</span> <span>Loot5</span> <span>Loot6</span>');
    lootis = $('div > span'); //getting the new spans in the changed div
  });

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span>Loot1</span>
  <span>Loot2</span>
  <span>Loot3</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
(function() {

var lootis = $('div > span');
var loot = 0

function loots() {
  lootis.each(function(e) {
    $(this).toggle(e >= loot && e < loot + 1);
  });
}
loots();

$('div').on('click', 'span', function(){
  loot = loot + 1;
  loots();
});

//Problem Starts Here:
$('div').on('contextmenu', 'span', function(){
  $('div').html('<span>Loot4</span> <span>Loot5</span> <span>Loot6</span>');
});

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span>Loot1</span>
  <span>Loot2</span>
  <span>Loot3</span>
</div>
```

Comment: problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

re-asign your variables after changing html of div ......... as below

```
 $('div').on('contextmenu', 'span', function(){
      $('div').html('<span>Loot5</span> <span>Loot6</span><span>Loot7</span>');
      lootis = $('div > span');
      loot = 0
      loots();
    });
```